# linux command mapping for long path dependent ones

Tags: linux, shell

I'm sorry if this question is asked in a different way before. I did my due search effort on Google and StackOverFlow(SOF), but the search terms that I tried haven't returned the answer I was looking for.

The problem is: I have installed Python virtualenv locally (that is, in "~/.local/") because I don't have sudo access to my school machine. The virtualenv now sits in "~/Download/modules/virtualenv-1.9.1/" and when I try to use it, I always have to type in something like:

```
$ python ~/Download/modules/virtualenv-1.9.1/virtualenv.py --distribute venv
```

I would like to do something like

```
$ virtualenv --distribute venv
```

I know I can add "alias" in "~/.cshrc" (or bash equivalent), but I'm wondering if there is alternative way to do this rather than adding more aliases. Sincere apology if this is a repeated (and naive/beginner) question. As I mentioned before, I wasn't successful in coming up with correct search terms to figure out the solution on Google/SOF. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can set a local variable. Try this out:

```
export MY_CUSTOM_VAR=/Users/YOURUSERNAMEHERE/Download/modules/virtualenv-1.9.1
```

Then you should be able to use `$MY_CUSTOM_VAR` in place of that directory in any command.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably put a script in `~/bin/venv`

```
#/bin/sh
exec python \
    ~/Download/modules/virtualenv-1.9.1/virtualenv.py \
    --distribute venv \
    "$@"
```

(make that executable with `chmod u+x ~/bin/venv`).

Don't forget to put `~/bin` in your `$PATH`.